# is it possible to assign constant values to attributes in xtext rule?

Tags: xtext

I have a metamodel in which I have a class `Range` with `min` a `max` integer values and I want to define an xText DSL, in which you can define a range like `1..10`, but also standard defaults like `?` and `!` that would stand for `0..1` or `1..1`. I looked around the documentation, but couldn't find any way to define this in the xText grammar. So far, I have a rule for the general case

`Range: min=INT '..' max=INT;`

However, I didn't find any way to define something like

`Range: '?' min=0 max=1;`

`Range: '!' min=1 max=1;`

How could I achieve similar behavior for my DSL?

Please note that I am not interested in generating a metamodel from the grammar, as the DSL models should adhere to an existing metamodel.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know an easy solution for that but you might be able to customize Xtexts object creation e.g. like

```
Model: ranges+=AbstractRange*;
AbstractRange returns Range: ExplicitRange | ZORange | OORange;
ExplicitRange returns Range: min=INT ".." max=INT;
ZORange returns Range: {Range} max=ZEROONE;
ZEROONE returns ecore::EInt: "?";
OORange returns Range: {Range} max=ONEONE;
ONEONE returns ecore::EInt: "!";
```

And following Customizations

```
class MyDslEcoreElementFactory extends DefaultEcoreElementFactory {

    @Inject extension MyDslGrammarAccess

    override set(EObject object, String feature, Object value, String ruleName, INode node) throws ValueConverterException {
        if (object instanceof Range) {
            if (ruleName == grammar.name+"."+ZEROONERule.name) {
                object.max = 1
                object.min = 0
                return;
            } else if (ruleName == grammar.name+"."+ONEONERule.name) {
                object.max = 1
                object.min = 1
                return;
            }

        }
        super.set(object, feature, value, ruleName, node)
    }

}
```

bound like this

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    override bindIAstFactory() {
        MyDslEcoreElementFactory
    }

}
```

unfortunately `org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IAstFactory.create(EClassifier)`
does not have a second param that specifies the node or rule you are in and you resist to introduce subclasses for the ranges (in a metamodel inherited from your one) which would make this a bit easy (override create only)